# Spotify: How to get truly random playback using playlist shuffle?

Tags: spotify, spotify-playlist

When playing Spotify playlists in shuffle mode (currently the only available mode for free accounts, while as a paying premium customer I can play in the original playlist order or in a pseudo-randomized shuffle mode), the tracks don't seem to be selected by an actual random function but rather by an algorithm that favors popular songs and misses out on seldom played songs, thus making me miss about 20% to 30% of the songs in my playlist. At least, this behavior seems plausible after reading experiments and reverse engineering by other users that matches my experience.

See:
https://community.spotify.com/t5/Ongoing-Issues/Shuffle-Is-Only-Going-Through-A-Handful-Of-Songs/idc-p/4557475

https://community.spotify.com/t5/Ongoing-Issues/Please-stop-marking-shuffle-complaints-as-quot-not-an-issue-quot/idi-p/1772030

Here is a feature request I posted in the spotify community:
https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/All-Platforms-Shuffle-algorithm-that-favours-quot-unpopular-quot/idi-p/4880823

There is also a more simplistic approach to prevent playing popular tracks too often by simple implementing a shuffle function like it has been used in devices such as mp3 players, as a feature request in the spotify community: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/All-Platforms-Option-to-have-a-true-shuffle/idi-p/4880594

Is it possible to tweak the algorithm to favor the seldom played songs instead? If so, how? Do I need an alternative spotify client? Are there any such clients?

Comment: As the suggested serendipity shuffle has been set to "not right now" by Spotify's product owners, here is a more simple approach: why not just reorder playlists randomly before playback exactly like this works on an ipod or in a youtube playlist: [community.spotify.com/t5/Idea-Submissions/non-algorithmic-playlist-shuffle/idi-p/5024739](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Idea-Submissions/non-algorithmic-playlist-shuffle/idi-p/5024739)

Comment: Here is an active feature request in the spotify community that has received quite some upvotes already: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/All-Platforms-Option-to-have-a-true-shuffle/idi-p/4880594